# Effective Spread Calculation in bond market by python

Tags: python, pandas, financial

I want to calculate effective spread rate in bond market.And have two data frame first trade data that is executed price and second is quote that contains buy and sell quotes for bonds.
Effective Spread Rate is calculated like below:

Effective spread:
Buy market order:  2×(pt−mt) 
Sell market order:  2×(mt−pt)
where  pt  is the price for the transaction at time  t, and  mt  is the mid quote at time  t−ε  (just before the trade).

Mid quote is :

```
quote['MidQuote'] = (quote['BuyPrice'] + quote['SellPrice'])/2.0
```

quote data is like this:

```
 Id    BuyTime      BuyPrice     Date       SellTime      SellPrice   MidQuote
 1     09:00:20      1005        2010-01-01 09:00:10      1001        1003
 1     09:10:21      1020        2010-01-01 09:10:25      1012        1016
 2     09:11:22      1032        2010-01-02 09:11:19      1020        1026
```

trade data is like this:

```
Id     Time        Date        Price
1      09:00:21    2010-01-01  1004
1      09:10:26    2010-01-01  1017
2      09:11:23    2010-01-02  2028
```

For instance Effective Spread rate for first row is like this:

2*(1004-1003) = 2

I should merge the data first.
I have searched internet and find this but i can not understand how he is done that
Here is the web address:

http://www.vincentgregoire.com/introduction-to-empirical-market-microstructure-in-python/

My Question is how could i merge this data and calculate this data by time. time is important because i should calculate difference between time t and  t−ε  (right before execution time).

Comment: Ain't this pandas ?

Comment: Yes it is.i edited it